# How can I see what POST data my IIS express instance is getting?

Tags: iis

I have a web app that uses web API. I also have an Arduino which is connected to the network which is generating JSON data.

When i get the arduino to print the raw JSON data, and i paste it into postman in Chrome, and submit it, it works fine. But when the arduino prepares and sends the same data it gets a response code of 411.

So, I want to be able to see what data is being posted back to my IIS express instance so I can troubleshoot the issue further. Is this at all possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with IIS Express. It may or may not have the functionality mentioned here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/01/02/enable-and-activate-failed-request-tracing-rules/. Apparently this will let you see the body. However this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352190/why-i-get-411-length-required-error says a 411 error means you are just missing content-length in the header

Comment: Yeah I added content length to the generated JSON. No more 411 but a different error (produced by the arduinojson library, -1)