# How to stop IIS Express 10.0 returning 411 LengthRequired

Tags: .net, iis, iis-express

I have a .NET 4.6.1 client application that uses `HttpWebRequest` to call a WebAPI hosted on IIS.  One of the calls is a POST request without a body that does not set the ContentLength header (`HttpWebRequest.ContentLength` has its default value -1, which indicates the property has not been set and that there is no request data to send).

- When I send this request to the WebAPI application hosted on IIS 8.5, the POST request works normally.
- Until recently, I was also able to send the request to the WebAPI running on IIS Express under the Visual Studio 2017 debugger, and again, it worked normally.  Unfortunately I no longer know exactly which version of IIS Express was being used.

Recently I repaved my development machine with Windows 10 Version 1909 and reinstalled the latest Visual Studio 2017 15.9.22.  Since doing this:

- Requests sent from by development machine to the WebAPI hosted remotely on IIS 8.5 continue to work normally.
- Requests sent to the WebAPI running locally on IIS Express 10.0.14358.1000 under the Visual Studio 2017 debugger are rejected with 411 LengthRequired.

I know that I can (and will eventually) [fix this by modifying my client code to set ContentLength = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352190/why-i-get-411-length-required-error).

But the client code is out in the field, and I'd like to fix this server-side if possible, e.g. by configuring IIS Express appropriately.

This looks to me like a breaking change in IIS behavior between IIS 8.5 and IIS Express 10.0.14358.1000, in that the latest IIS Express appears to be more restrictive in refusing to accept a POST without ContentLength header.

Is there a way of configuring IIS Express to behave as it used to?  Or some other way of fixing this without modifying client code?

Comment: Actually returning 411 is compliant to HTTP standard as well as other web server implementations, so I don't think there is an easy way to let IIS Express use the old behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review the request, you will see that the response is not returned from IIS but http.sys HTTP-API/2.0.

[image]

Since there is no registry can fix this, I'm afraid the only way to fix 411 is modify you client code. Otherwise, IIS express can't even accept the request.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows

Comment: So that seems to imply that upgrading Windows on a web server could break previously working applications.  I'd really like ot know what version of Windows / http.sys introduces this breaking change.  My development machine has http.sys 10.0.18362.295

Comment: Emmm.. I'm not able to post a request without content length even in an older WIN7 server. So I'm not sure whether this issue have something to do with IIS express or http.sys. It should be a standard behavior to handle the post request. Have you monitored the request header with fiddler in IIS 8.5 environment? Maybe the content-length get fixed in intermediate process.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, it must be something intermediate that's fixing the header.