# WOPI Host IIS 10.0 / http.sys allow POST requests to be empty

Tags: iis, ms-wopi, http.sys

OS: Windows Server 2019 Version 1809

IIS: 10.0.17763.1

When sending a POST request with no content, we are receiving an 411 error thrown by http.sys. I already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616296/how-to-stop-iis-express-10-0-returning-411-lengthrequired), but we cannot change the client code since the request are coming from a WOPI client. I also went through the [registy entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/iisadmin-service-inetinfo/httpsys-registry-windows) for http.sys but I couldn't find the correct one. It somehow must be possible, because there are [WOPI Hosts](https://github.com/microsoft/Office-Online-Test-Tools-and-Documentation/tree/master/samples/SampleWopiHandler) running with IIS. Since WOPI Hosts are nothing completely new, someone else must have stumbled across this issue.

Can I somehow tell http.sys to allow empty content for post requests or is this some kind of config for each WOPI client?

Comment: The 411 error in your link does not represent your problem, this error indicates that the server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content-Length header, you should check your Content-Length.

Comment: You should keep in mind that IIS/http.sys does not allow much customization either. So, if like you said you "cannot change the client code", then you stuck on both sides, and might have to develop a "proxy" app in the middle to bridge the gaps. Not easy but doable.

Comment: @LexLi That is indeed our current workaround. We have a proxy that sets the Content-Length to 0 if there is none. It works but we hoped for a better solution